# phonegap - nothing happend on npm install -g phonegap

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I've been trying to install phonegap with no luck.

I've already installed nodejs using:

```
sudo apt-get install node
```

But when I tried to run the following, nothing was outputted to the terminal. See attached image.

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Package name should be "nodejs" not "node".

Also make sure npm is installed by typing :

```
npm -v
```

in terminal.

Please read [Installing Node.js via package manager](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager) for Node.js & NPM installation.